# Is there a way to make the main page only display a brief description of the full article?

Tags: plugins, posts

I want to make a new blog which only has a brief description of the article on the main page, instead of a shortened version of it.  I want to make the brief description of the article myself.

Is there any way to do this, or any plugin which allows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on [Excerpts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt).
They are hidden onder the 'screen options' in the right top corner of add/edit screens.

And on the front page call [`the_exerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) instead of `the_content()`.